# How can I send an HTML email from a browser client?

Tags: email

I want to send an email in HTML to a user from browser client i.e send mail from Gmail, Yahoo, etc.

I paste the HTML I want to send in the text area, but the HTML is not getting rendered when I receive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML emails need a `content-type: text/html` header otherwise they are assumed to be plain text. You do not mention what language you are using, but if you are using PHP, you can use [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to make sending HTML emails a little easier.

Comment: im not using any language atm i just want to check the format of the output of a jsp file which im generating which will be sent as mail i just copied the html due to the jsp and sent it as a mail to myself from different accounts to check whether the image in mail is getting blocked by gmail or not

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea>` tag is for user input. Users can't insert any data in mails, so this tag won't be rendered. If you just showing the information, use tag `<p>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-html-email/19672/

Be careful with how you use this though, GMail could very well blacklist you if your recipient list is too long. I use it all the time for tests.